# Change string list to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I saved a list to a file as a string. In particular, I did:

```
f = open('myfile.txt','w')
f.write(str(mylist))
f.close()
```

But, later when I open this file again, take the (string-ified) list, and want to change it back to a list, what happens is something along these lines:

```
>>> list('[1,2,3]')
['[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ']']
```

Could I make it so that I got the list [1,2,3] from the file?

Comment: you're going to get a million different answers, but in descending order of preference you should 1) use a real serialization protocol like `json`, `pickle`, or `shelve` 2) use `ast.literal_eval` 3) manually do some janky parsing yourself.  Notably not appearing: regular `eval`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Curious, what's your point?

Comment: @SteveJessop I'll have to agree. But even a lot of high-rep users often do that, particularly if they don't want to start a discussion with the OP, or competition against other answers.

Comment: @zhangxaochen I mean _other_ high-rep users :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two easiest major options here. First, using [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
[1, 2, 3]
```

Unlike `eval`, this is safer since it will only evaluate python literals, such as lists, dictionaries, NoneTypes, strings, etc. This would throw an error if we use a code inside.

Second, make use of the `json` module, using [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[1,2,3]')
[1, 2, 3]
```

A great advantage of using `json` is that it's cross-platform, and you can also write to file easily.

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump([1, 2, 3], f)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [285]: import ast

In [286]: ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
Out[286]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval` whenever possible:
[ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate[s] an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.

Edit: Also, consider using [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). `json.loads` operates on a different string format, but is generally faster than `ast.literal_eval`. (So if you use `json.load`, be sure to save your data using `json.dump`.) Moreover, the [JSON format](http://www.json.org/) is language-independent.

Comment: and here is a post explains why *eval is evil*: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Answer (score 1):

I would write python objects to file using the built-in json encoding or, if you don't like json, with pickle and cpickle. Both allow for easy deserialization and serialization of data. I'm on my phone but when I get home I'll upload sample code.

EDIT:
Ok, get ready for a ton of Python code, and some opinions...

**JSON**

Python has builtin support for JSON, or JavaScript Object Notation, a lightweight data interchange format. JSON supports Python's basic data types, such as dictionaries (which JSON calls *objects*: basically just key-value pairs, and *lists*: comma-separated values encapsulated by [ and ]. For more information on JSON, see [this resource](http://www.json.org/). Now to the code:

```
import json #Don't forget to import
my_list = [1,2,"blue",["sub","list",5]]
with open('/path/to/file/', 'w') as f:
  string_to_write = json.dumps(my_list) #Dump the string
  f.write(string_to_write)
  #The character string [1,2,"blue",["sub","list",5]] is written to the file
```

Note that the `with` statement will close the file automatically when the block finishes executing.

To load the string back, use

```
with open('/path/to/file/', 'r') as f:
  string_from_file = f.read()
 mylist = json.loads(string_from_file) #Load the string
  #my_list is now the Python object [1,2,"blue",["sub","list",5]]
```

I like JSON. Use JSON unless you really, really have a good reason for not.

**CPICKLE**

Another method for serializing Python data to a file is called pickling, in which we write more than we 'need' to a file so that we have some meta-information about how the characters in the file relate to Python objects. There is a builtin `pickle` class, but we'll use `cpickle`, because it is implemented in C and is much, much faster than `pickle` (about 100X but I don't have a citation for that number). The dumping code then becomes

```
import cpickle #Don't forget to import
with open('/path/to/file/', 'w') as f:
  string_to_write = cpickle.dumps(my_list) #Dump the string
  f.write(string_to_write)
  #A very weird character string is written to the file, but it does contain the contents of our list
```

To load, use

```
with open('/path/to/file/', 'r') as f:
  string_from_file = f.read()
  mylist = cpickle.loads(string_from_file) #Load the string
  #my_list is now the Python object [1,2,"blue",["sub","list",5]]
```

**Comparison**

Note the similarities between the code we wrote using JSON and the code we wrote using cpickle. In fact, the only major difference between the two methods is what text (which characters) gets actually written to the file. I believe JSON is faster and more space-efficient than cpickle - but cpickle is a valid alternative. Also, JSON format is much more universal than cpickle's weird syntax.

**A note on eval**

Please don't use `eval()` haphazardly. It seems like you're relatively new to Python, and `eval` can be a risky function to jump right into. It allows for the unchecked evaluation of any Python code, and as such can be a) risky, if you ever are relying on the user to input text, and b) can lead to sloppy, non-Pythonic code.

That last point is just my two cents.

**tl:dr; Use JSON to dump and load Python objects to file**

Answer (score 1):

Python developers traditionally use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to serialize their data and write it to a file.

You could do so like so:

```
import pickle
mylist = [1,2,3]
f = open('myfile', 'wb')
pickle.dump(mylist, f)
```

And then reopen like so:

```
import pickle
f = open('myfile', 'rb')
mylist = pickle.load(f) # [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Well, Python developers who want a horrible, insecure solution.

Comment: @Wooble could you explain?

Comment: @jmu303: it's possible to create a file that when unpickled executes arbitrary code. This is "insecure" if your user's filesystem is insecure, i.e. if an attacker can place a malicious file in the location your program saves to and more importantly loads from.

Comment: @Wooble My answer is not a referendum on Python's de facto method of data persistence. My answer is very much correct. But if it pleases you to downvote it, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write to file without brackets: `f.write(str(mylist)[1:-1])`
2. After reading the line, split it to get a list: `data = line.split(',')`
3. To convert to integers: `data = map(int, data)`